# Android studio alway show "Gradle project sync in progress"

Tags: android, android-studio

After update android studio Build number AI-141.1809159 version=1.2 in Canary update, i can't sync gradle project and always show "Gradle project sync in progress"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Following are the steps that I use (Kind a workaround),

1. Edit the root build.gradle file (adding a new line to file will also
   do).
2. Save the file.
3. Restart the IDE (File->Invalid Cache/Restart->Just Restart).
   Gradle Sync in progress notification should go away.

Comment: worked for me(though now showing another problem), hence upvote

Comment: Worked  for me too ! Funny bug

Answer (score 2):

I found this was due to this plugin being used in AS:

'Android Studio Unit Test'

To disable this in AS 1.2 do the following:

File > Settings > Plugins > Android Studio Unit Test disable

Comment: Both this method and after that @vijay_t 's answer worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved, just update android sdk, it's work for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I don't see the Gradle console detail either...  I might reinstall need to update Studio.

Comment: Upgraded to 1.2 and now this message won't go away.  "Gradle project sync in progress..."

Comment: Same here, upgraded from 1.1 to 1.2 and started to see this message. Everything is working but the message is always there on top of the editor window. I've updated all my android: sdk, ndk, tools to the latest but that didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: There is an issue in the google bug tracker about this problem. See link: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=169829

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me twice and had to do with one of the gradle files having a date in the future (a glitch in Android Studio it seems).  That is why just adding a space to the file and saving can fix the problem, as described above.  Or go through your project with the operating system file explorer to find the file.

Answer (score 0):

wait for some time, if you are using somebody else repo. It depends on the projects buildings. You might see new changes like file path, project-level dir appearing, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Disable VPN if you have it active.