# Can't Load project in android studio

Tags: android

My laptop crashed while android studio was running (probably due to some corrupted files). I reinstalled the windows and installed android studio again , but when I tried to load my previous project , it only says **Gradle project sync in progress** and remains in the same state. I have
tried to open a new project but same goes for it.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem could be related to build.gradle file. Please, try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30692397/15449752) by [@vijay_t](https://ed%20Jun%207,%202015%20at%2010:19%20user%20avatar%20vijay_t). 
Also try to disable android studio plugins.

Comment: I have tried both of them , but don't know why its not working.

Comment: I just invalidated cache and restarted the AS several times.  Thank You.